# Create a web application that incorporates Node.js, MongoDb and D3.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, d3.js

I want to build a web application that displays data from some sites.
To do this I thought about automating data collection by doing web scraping.
So I take data from these sites, I format them to my pleasure and save them on MongoDb.

So now I would like to view this data using D3.js. It's not the first time I use D3 but it's the first time I have an application that uses Node.js and MongoDb.
I usually had some data in a .csv file and built simple graphs using HTML, CSS, Javascript and D3.js.
Usually my projects in D3 had this structure:

*index.html*:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./heatmap.css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="container-heatmap"></div>
      <div id="container-sparkline"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="container-legend"></div>
   <script src="./heatmap.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

*heatmap.js*:

```
var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 210};
var width = 850 - margin.right - margin.left;
var height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom; //400

var svg = d3.select('#container-heatmap')
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// some code...

// load data files
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.csv, './data.csv')
   .await(createHeatmap);

function createHeatmap(error, data) {
    if(error) {
      console.log("*** Error loading files: " + error + " ***");
      throw error;
   }

   // some code...

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .selectAll('text')
        .attr('font-weight', 'normal');

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll('text')
        .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("dx", ".8em")
        .attr("dy", ".5em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(-65)";
        });
}
```

*heatmap.css*:

```
#container {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100;
    height: 100%;
}

// come code...
```

Now, I've created an app in Node.js that does web scraping and saves data in a MongoDB `test` collection.

This is the structure of my project:

```
data
helpers
 |_ util.js = file that contains useful functions for different files (for example: printOnFile)
middlewares
 |_ mongolib.js = file that contains functions that are used to interact with the database. For example: connectToDb(), disconnectFromDb(), insert(), find(), ...
models
node_modules
output
 |_ data.json = file that contains the data saved on the db. Before inserting data on the db, I save them also on file. This file has this structure:
    [
        {To: 'aa1', B: 'bb1', C: 'cc1'},
        {To: 'aa2', B: 'bb2', C: 'cc2'},
        {To: 'aa3', B: 'bb3', C: 'cc3'},
        {To: 'aa4', B: 'bb4', C: 'cc4'},
        ...
    ]
routers
 |_ scraper.js = file that contains useful functions for doing web scraping

app.js = main file of the app
package.json
package-lock.json
```

*app.js* is like this one:

```
// import some packages and some my files
var mongolib = require('./middlewares/mongolib.js');
var scrape = require('./routers/scraper.js');

const mainApp = async function() {
    const conn = await mongolib.connectToDb(); // init: connect to db and create collection test
    await scrapeSiteAndSaveData(); // get data
    await mongolib.disconnectFromDb(); // disconnect from MongoDb
    await console.log('DATA VIZ'); // data visualization here?
    return 'end';
}

mainApp()
    .then(res => console.log(res)) 
    .catch(err => console.log(err)); 

async function scrapeSiteAndSaveData() {
    await scrape.downloadAndSave();
}
```

So, for now, I only have the back-end part. How can I incorporate the front-end part (the one related to the visualization of the graphs in D3.js)?

In which folder should the new files be created? What structure should they have?
I did not find tutorials that covered this topic.
The only one I found is [this](https://anmolkoul.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/interactive-data-visualization-using-d3-js-dc-js-nodejs-and-mongodb/) but it does not help much. What is the best way to create such an app? Are there any standards that are better to follow?

Thanks!

Comment: it oke if it include express ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif It's fine even if it includes Express.

Comment: ok I did post an aswer that will fix your issue

Comment: Have you ever looked at [node-red](http://nodered.org)? it already uses the node.js express server, can serve static files, and has nodes to read/write to mongo db, and display IoT data in live graphs...

Answer (score 2):

to be able to serv the files to the frontEnd , your App.js need to be setup as an `Http server`

Since you're ok with a solution that include `Expressjs`

after installing Express , in your `app.js` include this code to start a webserver

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set("port",process.env.PORT||300)
var server = app.listen(app.get("port"),()=>{
  console.log("Listening on PORT: "+ app.get("port"))
});
app.use("/",express.static('public_html')) // we serve the files in this directory
```

i used `public_html` just for the purpose of demonstration it can be what ever you want

Now your folder structur will look something like this

```
helpers
 |_ util.js = file that contains useful functions for different files (for example: printOnFile)
middlewares
 |_ mongolib.js = file that contains functions that are used to interact with the database. For example: connectToDb(), disconnectFromDb(), insert(), find(), ...
models
node_modules
output
public_html<------- You put here all your HTML file, css and JS related to the client side
 |_ data.json = file that contains the data saved on the db. Before inserting data on the db, I save them also on file. This file has this structure:
    [
        {To: 'aa1', B: 'bb1', C: 'cc1'},
        {To: 'aa2', B: 'bb2', C: 'cc2'},
        {To: 'aa3', B: 'bb3', C: 'cc3'},
        {To: 'aa4', B: 'bb4', C: 'cc4'},
        ...
    ]
routers
 |_ scraper.js = file that contains useful functions for doing web scraping

app.js = main file of the app
package.json
package-lock.json
```

after that just lunch your server `node app.js` and access it via your webbrowser